# Signal when a QListView selection changes due to keyboard activity?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlistview

I have a QDialog, created with QT Designer, that looks like so: [image: Dialog]

The list of servers on the left is a QListView with a QStringListModel. Mouse clicking an item in the list view updates the form with the information for the selected item by connecting the view’s activated(QModelIndex) signal to a slot function in the dialog.

However, pressing up or down on the keyboard also changes the selected item, but no signal is emitted, so the form isn't updated to match the selected item. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `activated(QModelIndex)` signal actually refers to something more than just the act of selecting. The concept is rather vague, but it's more like an act of explicit choosing. If you're just looking for notification that the current selection has changed, you can grab the selection model and connect to its updates.

```
MyView::MyView() {
   QListView* view = new QListView(this);
   connect(view->selectionModel(), 
      SIGNAL(selectionChanged(QItemSelection,QItemSelection)), 
      this, SLOT(handleSelectionChanged(QItemSelection)));
}

...

MyView::handleSelectionChanged(const QItemSelection& selection){
   if(selection.indexes().isEmpty()) {
      clearMyView();
   } else {
      displayModelIndexInMyView(selection.indexes().first());
   }
}
```

In the code above, `displayModelIndexInMyView(QModelIndex)` should be replaced with your current handler slot for `activated(QModelIndex)`, and `clearMyView()` replaced with whatever it is that you want to do when there's nothing selected.

There's a lot of ways to do this, and honestly I'm not sure what is the canonical one, but I think this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can get the signal/slot to connect. At runtime I get the following error: "No such slot ConnectDialog::handleSelectionChanged(QItemSelection)". The function exists and looks just like yours... any ideas?

Comment: Did you put it under `private slots:` when you declared it in the header?

Comment: D'oh... No I didn't. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I would suggest to use `currentChanged()` signal instead of `selectionChanged()`. It should provide you with a little bit cleaner solution since you don't need to support multiple selections.

Comment: @DmitryVolosnykh There is no such signal.

Comment: @NikosC. I think he's referring to [`QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#currentChanged)

Comment: "The concept is rather vague, but it's more like an act of explicit choosing" -- `activate` is a generalized version of double-clicked and includes the keyboard equivalent (pressing Enter)

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to implement `QListView::currentChanged(...)` virtual function.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled also on a similar case with Qt6. In addition to the accepted answer, I propose this, with the new syntax it becomes (example non tested):

```
MyView::MyView() {
   QListView* view = new QListView(this);
   connect(view->selectionModel(), 
      &QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged, 
      this, &MyView::handleSelectionChanged);
}

...

MyView::handleSelectionChanged(
        const QItemSelection& selection,
        const QItemSelection& before){
   if(selection.indexes().isEmpty()) {
      clearMyView();
   } else {
      displayModelIndexInMyView(selection.indexes().first());
   }
}
```